# load library by initial value - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use `mPDF` library in `codeigniter` framework.

```
//if I include this library 

include("MPDF57/mpdf.php");
mpdf = new mPDF('c')
```

now, in `codeigniter` framework how can pass a initial value to this library ?

```
        $this->load->library('pdf');
        $pdf = $this->pdf->load();
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://arjunphp.com/generating-a-pdf-in-codeigniter-using-mpdf/)

Comment: initial value means?? can you clear bit more??

Comment: how to pass a value to constructor of a library in codeigniter?